# VMWare Host-only network Gateway?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, gateway, windows-server-2019

I have VMWare Workstation 15.5 installed on my computer with Windows Server 2019 Evaluation copy as a guest OS. I want to configure the server operating system as a DHCP server (hence why it is disabled in the virtual network settings.) and am having trouble setting it up. I cannot figure out what IP to use as the default gateway. 
This is the [server's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnAdb.png) IPv4 settings, and here is the [Virtual Network Editor's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezD1C.png) setings.

Answer (score 0):

None. Your host's uplink connection is through a different interface, not this interface – so it shouldn't specify anything here.

Answer (score 0):

Your Guest needs a NAT interface so you can configure DHCP on the Guest to work through the NAT interface. Host-onlyu will not work and Bridged has DHCP outside the host machine, so NAT is your only possible choice.